# Excel date/time conversion not working correctly

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have strings like `Oct 02 2015  11:04` which I'm trying to convert into valid datetime format. I have seperated everything using Text-To-Columns but the time seems to be incorrect.

Cell `E1` value is `11:04:00` and when running `=TIME(LEFT(E1,2), RIGHT(E1,2), 0)`, the result is `12:11 AM`

The cell is formatted as `h:mm AM/PM`, I would expect the value to be `11:04 AM`. What am I doing wrong?

Images for clarification:

Time formula not working:
[image: Time formula not working]

Contents of the cell:
[image: Contents of the cell]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your time is already stored as time, and when you perform any text actions on it, that's done on the numerical version of it (one day = 1, one hour = 1/24 ... 11:04 = 0.46111)

[image]

Why do you want to process it further?

Comment: I was wondering if this was the case. I'm trying to build a full datetime value that can be used for calculations and sorting but when I tried to add the date and time together (using `DATEVALUE` and `TIMEVALUE`) it kept giving me errors. I just assumed the format of the time was incorrect. I've now managed to figure it out - add the values without further formulas like `DATEVALUE` - but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you shouldn't use `TIME` function. It is not the correct function since `TIME` invloved some "day and hours" conversation. For my own approach I will use `=TEXT(E1,"h:mm AM/PM")` for the solution